# Response.WriteFile("mymenu.aspx") Bug?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using `Response.WriteFile("mymenu.aspx")` to write a plain text file out to an area in a `MasterPage`.  Unfortunately it's also printing out an unknown character represented by the square character.  The contents of the menu file are as followings:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="Accounts">Accounts</a></li>
</ul>
```

The square character is what is causing my menu to display incorrectly, pushing it down about 20 pixels.  I tested putting just the HTML in the master page instead of including the file and it works fine which mean it must be down to the `Response.WriteFile` function.  I don't suppose anyone else has encountered this problem?

**EDIT**: I tried the following as well, just to really make sure I wasn't doing anything stupid and that the file didn't contain anything dodgy.

```
<%
   Dim tw As New System.IO.StreamReader(Server.MapPath("menu.aspx"))
   For Each s As String In tw.ReadToEnd
      Response.Write(s)
   Next
%>
```

It worked.  But that still doesn't explain Response.WriteFile behaviour.

Comment: weird...call Microsoft Product Support:-)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a character encoding issue. Is this file in the same encoding as the page your using it from?

## Edit

Open the file up in a hex editor make sure there are no weird characters in there.

Comment: I've tried Response.ContentType = "plain/text" without any luck.

Comment: Aye, seems more like a problem to do with Response.WriteFile as opposed to the actual file itself.  I tried it with a plain text file too and still had the exact same problem.  I can re-create it and have the same problem.

Comment: Hmm weird you use Fiddler to watch the html over the wire?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your text file in an editor that will show all characters including carriage returns, line feeds etc. (Notepad++ is my choice). File may have an unusual eof marker or other encoding issue from the software that created the file.

Comment: That was the first thing I checked, and I deal with incorrect character sets all the time.  Definitely not a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it rendered correctly for me.

I have seen ASP.NET alter incoming XML strings in WebMethods before.  Save the text to a file on disk before you Response.Write it to compare.  Check your CSS for your LI style.